# P-value and the alpha value are equal while normal approximating the binomial distribution

Tags: hypothesis-testing, p-value

I am trying to normal approximate a binominal distribution. I found that the p value obtained from the result is equal to the alpha value given. Should I then accept the null hypothesis or reject the null hypothesis.

```
> z=(pbar-pi.H0)/sqrt(pi.H0*(1-pi.H0)/n)
> z
[1] 1.591487
> (87/121 - 0.65)/sqrt(0.65*0.35/121)
[1] 1.591487
> pnorm(z,lower.tail = F)
[1] 0.05575001
> prop.test(87,121,0.65,alternative = "greater",conf.level = 0.95,correct = FALSE)

    1-sample proportions test without continuity correction

data:  87 out of 121, null probability 0.65
X-squared = 2.5328, df = 1, p-value = 0.05575
alternative hypothesis: true p is greater than 0.65
95 percent confidence interval:
 0.6475729 1.0000000
sample estimates:
        p 
0.7190083
```

Comment: There is no correct answer. You have to decide before the test if you are going to reject or fail to reject when $p=\alpha$. Remember you never accept the null hypothesis.

Comment: @Hugh Certainly when one is using exact rather than approximate calculations, there is a formally correct answer, which follows directly from the definitions of $\alpha$ and $p$ (and this one is already answered on site -- you definitely reject when $p$ is exactly $\alpha$, keeping in mind that this exact equality can only actually happen when the distribution of the test statistic is discrete). When one is doing approximate calculations, it is best to clarify what we're trying to achieve  ... ctd

Comment: ctd ... (I'd be inclined to do a more accurate calculation, as being most likely to avoid dealing with complaints, even though $\alpha$ is likely arbitrary in any case -- I usually don't really care that much if my type I error rate is out a little bit, so often it's more a dealing-with-perceptions issue)

Comment: Round up and report it as p <= 0.051 if you are satisfied and convinced. To argue that 0.049 is significant while 0.051 is not is a game played only by people accustomed to equivocal results.